# React Native Navigation on axios request success

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation

```
_signInAsync() {
if (this.state.mobile === '') {
  alert('Please provide a valid mobile number');
  return false;
}
return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/otp/request/' 
+this.state.mobile)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.data.otp);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('OtpConfirm');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
```

I Cannot navigate to screen on axios request success. Please Help me.

```
const AppStack = StackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen 
});
const AuthStack = StackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen, OtpConfirm: 
OtpConfirmScreen });

export default SwitchNavigator({
AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
App: AppStack,
Auth: AuthStack
},
{
initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
}
);
```

Above is the root navigation file and I used SwitchNavigator for seperating auth screens and others

Comment: Can you add how you're calling the function, is it referenced or not and your navigation stack?

Comment: try to write `this._signInAsync = this._signInAsync.bind(this)` in constructor of component.

Comment: @PritishVaidya: <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]} onPress={() => this._signInAsync()}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Send  Code</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: @punksta: already tried it and failed.

Comment: Also edit your question to add the navigation routes file.